# R: Plotting importance feature using FeatureImp$new

Tags: r, xgboost, mlr

Here is the code

```
library(mlr)
library(xgboost)
library(iml)
data("iris")
tsk = makeClassifTask(data = iris, target = "Species")
lrn = makeLearner("classif.xgboost",predict.type = "prob")
mod = mlr:::train(lrn, tsk)
X = iris[which(names(iris) != "Species")]
predictor = Predictor$new(mod, data = X, y = iris$Species)
imp = FeatureImp$new(predictor, loss = "ce")
```

I got the following error

```
imp = FeatureImp$new(predictor, loss = "ce")
Warning in predict.WrappedModel(model, newdata = newdata) :
  Provided data for prediction is not a pure data.frame but from class data.table, 
  hence it will be converted.
```

> Error in estimate.feature.imp(feature, data.sample = data.sample, y = y,  : 
>         task 1 failed - "Feature names stored in `object` and `newdata` are different!"

I tried checking the feature names in model and data but both of them are similar. Hence, I dont understand what exactly is this error
"Feature names stored in `object` and `newdata` are different!"

```
colnames(X)
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 

mod$learner.model$feature_names    
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
```

Comment: Where are `Predictor` and `FeatureImp` coming from?

Comment: they are from iml package

Comment: Looks like a bug in the iml package -- I get an error when running the example from the help as well. You should [open an issue](https://github.com/christophM/iml/issues) for this.

Comment: I opened an issue: https://github.com/christophM/iml/issues/46

Answer (score 0):

This is a `xgboost` issue: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1809

Its about the order of the variables.

```
X = X[mod$learner.model$feature_names]
```

should solve it. I faced the same issue some days ago.

Edit: The error still occurs, probably because there is again some disordering due to the shuffling by `iml`. But the fix is definitely the way to go, as this error also occurs for predict calls using `xgboost`.